# MVC 5 custom 404 page displaying "Object moved to here." message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I see a bunch of similar questions on SO but most of them are caused by redirecting. This, however, is also caused when going directly to the custom 404 route.

I created an error controller with the following action that I want to use for handling 404 errors:

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;

    return View();
}
```

In the project's Web.config I've added this to `<system.webServer>`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/notfound" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

When I navigate directly to the `/error/notfound`route on my site it displays my custom view but it is having "Object moved to here." injected into it. Do I have something incorrectly configured? If I remove `Response.StatusCode = 404;` from the controller action it works correctly but then the page returns HTTP 200.

Comment: Have you checked the StatusDescription of the Response within your NotFound action?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to be the same text.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to set `Response.StatusDescription` 
something like;

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusDescription = "";
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. As a quick solution you can clear Response's content.

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
Response.ClearContent();
```

I do this in Error View page.